# How to make md Content scrollable in Angular material Design

Tags: html, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am using ui-view in md-content  to display a list but its getting overflow i want list in md-content should be scrollable
here is my index.html

```
<div layout-lt-lg="row" class="screen-bg">
    <div flex-lt-lg="100">

        <!--header-->
        <md-toolbar class="app-bar-bg" style="background-color: #9013fe;">
            <div class="status-bar-bg"></div>
            <div class="md-toolbar-tools">

                <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Settings">
                    <!--<md-icon md-svg-icon="app/images/back1.svg"></md-icon>-->
                </md-button>
                <h2>
                    <span></span>
                </h2>
                <span flex=""></span>
                <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Favorite">
                    <!--<md-icon md-svg-icon="app/images/a.svg"></md-icon>-->
                </md-button>

            </div>
        </md-toolbar>

        <!--content-->
        <div>
            <md-content>

                <ui-view></ui-view>
            </md-content>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my template

```
 <md-list flex>
        <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="broadCast in broadCasts">
          <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" >
            <h3>{{broadCast.name}}</h3>
            <h3>{{broadCast.phone}}</h3>
          </div>
        </md-list-item>
 </md-list>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the list scrollable:

1. Add a class to md-list.

   ```
   <md-list class="make-scrollable" flex>
     <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="broadCast in broadCasts">
       <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
         <h3>{{broadCast.name}}</h3>
         <h3>{{broadCast.phone}}</h3>
       </div>
     </md-list-item>
   </md-list>
   ```
2. Style the md-list in your css file like so:

   ```
   md-list.make-scrollable {
       height: 600px; //Or any other height you wish
       overflow-y: scroll;
   }
   ```

That should make the overflowing content scrollable

Answer (score 0):

You are using too many unnecessary container elements.

```
<div layout-lt-lg="row" flex-lt-lg="100" class="screen-bg">
    <!--header-->
    <md-toolbar class="app-bar-bg" style="background-color: #9013fe;">
        <div class="status-bar-bg"></div> //desired controller buttons
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools"></div> //desired controller buttons
    </md-toolbar>

    <!--content-->
   <md-content flex ui-view>
   </md-content>
</div>
```

Here is a working example. There are some changes but basic structure is almost same.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'm using angular components and the md-content is wrapped in a component element <my-component>. I see no option to drop the component element beside dropping the component at all. The component keeps scaling and I have no idea how to make it scrollable beside giving it a fixed height.